# Getting Android TextView to Scroll with ExpandableTextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview

I have an expandablelistview in my layout, and I want to place a textview below the expandablelistview, such that when I scroll to the bottom of screen, the textview will be displayed at then end of the expandablelistview.

I couldn't just place the textview below the expandablelistview, because if there are more items in the expandablelistview than the screen can fit, I can only scroll down to the last item in the expandablelistview, not to the textview.

Thus, I tried encompassing both the expandablelistview and textview in a scrollview, but when doing this the height of the expandablelistview is only as high as one group member, and does not fill the whole screen even when the layout_height parameter is set to match_parent. I tried setting fillViewport for the ScrollView as true, which allows the expandablelistview to be displayed properly, but then I can only scroll down to the last item in the expandablelistview, and not the textview.

I would like to make it such that I can scroll to down to the TextView, but cannot figure out how to do so. Below is the xml code. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/results"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offer_bttn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Offer"
            android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bttn_gold_border_white_background"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listview"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```